# LMA - notification on licence change

Tags: licenses, lma

I dont know if this is the right place to post such question, but after endless hours googling, i didnt find the answer to this. I have this usecase: A org buy our application via AppExchange and it creates a lead/license to my production org via LMA. Then i use a "before insert" trigger to activate a servise on my end and therefore enable the user who bought it access to my servises(running on different servers). My question is: If the buyer org Admin buy 10 licenses for his org, asing then to first 10 users and then reasing them to another 10, is there any way LMA to notify me about that reassigment, so i can stop old users license and start new users one on my end? Will really appritiate any help here, as SF documentation doesnt even mention it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK the LMA org only offers license counts not individual license assignments. That leaves you having to add code into your application to do the notification.

This post [Get the list of users licensed for a Managed Package](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21180/get-the-list-of-users-licensed-for-a-managed-package) shows the sorts of queries you can do. But I don't think those objects support triggers, so you would have to e.g. provide an admin page that manually checks those objects and does the notification and tell customers they must run that page when a new User is setup if they want the application to work.